# Invertible matrix is similar to Unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Statement that Every Unitary matrix is invertible is true.

but, opposite statement is also true? "Every invertible matrix is similar to Unitary matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:every eigenvalue of a unitary matrix has modulus equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you! This hint helped me a lot.